# find owner of private key

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, ssh, git

On one of the old dev servers I manage there is an RSA public and private key pair  *~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub*  and  *~/.ssh/id_rsa* in a staging user account (used for automation and testing prior to production).

It had been converted into a VPS. Because it is still very much in service, `pull`ing from Bitbucket iterating weekly through many separate but related projects, each on carefully chosen schedules, it is crucial that the same ssh key retain read-write access to those repositories.  The QA processes occasionally make robotic updates that `git push` meta data back up the *remote origin*s. The identity (keys) must not change.

I read through 
 https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-cloud-221449711.html and other online resources but find myself at a loss how to grant this email-less identity write access to new repositories (eg. forks) on difference Bitbucket accounts.

Although I possess the original SSH key for that robot staging account, I don't have access to its Bitbucket account (if any) because I simply don't know which one it is, and have exhausted all possibilities.  However its public key cannot be added to any other BB account (using **Add key** at https://bitbucket.org/account/user/MEMEME/ssh-keys/ ), stating it's already taken.

That is fine; I don't want to link it to the entire account anyway, but only to specific repos under **Access management** at
https://bitbucket.org/USER/PROJECT/admin/access

Trouble is, at that URL one can only submit Bitbucket usernames or *working* email addresses, ***not public ssh keys.***  The dev account setup behind this robot identity has never had its domains' MX records nor mail boxes etc. setup to actually receive email--only enough to satisfy **git config** from complaining--and I had gone through many possibilities anyway.  All bounced back or failed to end up in catch-all boxes.

This leaves me in a bit of a pickle.

Any ideas how given either a pub or priv ssh key, I can find the owner/associated email addresses (even if broken) out in the wild?

The real goal would be to grant this account write access to *fork*ed repositories, not the originals.

```
# ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDYBzHi7y9szZz5um3JLPSYPm3LYTVTzkGl8v58dhiIBDA+8xXlpMJQGFZHT0zmg8+Y+409qQQKzbILcx
T6/rYt5HE57GFNK5DRwaKMCCICabVHF0aJKf9mKlY9fY2TwCZP7ufeISA88pQNQIHpPIuDDy1vFO6yBkkVx8aPIH0q/bvCVE89W+8fpGgdwKq9+dDB0KZp1X
3VMYF0IsJRpH5OGWaQDQHHxJX+sudyWtABlQ3UAgWyp0hkmx1q1kulahk1BrX1wrJOdOrxgpwBnRVHm6dEyJR6j7pK3ZR+4duQqHVkOP//J6RQsdK/voPrSE
z2C0tuuuJn1hBwSJxkn4VN web@staging
```

Comment: How did my pubic key show up in a pastebin, minutes after posting here? http://pastebin.com/cxB8Wtp3  Another interesting security question. :)

Comment: definitely shady but could be a bot that scans for people posting publickey/privatekey like messages?

Comment: Do the meta data changes show in "recent activity"? That might help you identify the user account.

Comment: @axl  Nay, it never makes it past the shell after `git push` in the first place. "Please make sure you have the correct access rights...."

Comment: @axl  Your hint is valid. I had referred to the post-fork commits where they are needed. When I checked a pre-fork repo's commit history, one such "Staging Robot" pops up with "Unmapped user.
This user is not recognised in Bitbucket." So that's a clue. Though not much I didn't already know.
Kind of takes me back to the "who has my key?" question.

Comment: Unmapped means the bot commit used a user/email that BitBucket doesn't recognize. The recent event log should show which account did the push. Not sure if you can find a full log of that anywhere.